# discord.py Sending DM through python console

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am trying to send a message through the python console. Right now, I have everything working when I set it as a bot command (When I do the command `!dm`, I get prompted in the python console The user Id and message I want to DM. This all works. However, what I am trying to do is for the program to prompt me as soon as it is started.

My current code:

```
@bot.command(name='dm')
async def messageinput(ctx):
    member = input('Enter Member ID: ')
    message = input('Enter Message: ')
    print(member)
    print(message)
    user = bot.get_user(int(member))
    await user.send(message)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    #await verifyloop()
    print(Fore.CYAN + '|------------------------------------------|')
    print(Fore.CYAN + '|--------------Bot is online!--------------|')
    print(Fore.CYAN + '|------------------------------------------|')
    
    #await messageinput()
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a discord member using their ID in the `on_ready()` function, you do this:

```py
await client.fetch_user(USER_ID)
```

Where `USER_ID` is the user's ID (an integer value).

---

So, your event would look like this:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(Fore.CYAN + '|------------------------------------------|')
    print(Fore.CYAN + '|--------------Bot is online!--------------|')
    print(Fore.CYAN + '|------------------------------------------|')

    member = int(input('Enter Member ID: '))
    message = input('Enter Message: ')

    user = await bot.fetch_user(member)
    await user.send(message)
```

Comment: Like I said, I already have it working as a bot command. However, I want it to prompt me when I start the program (So I do not have to open discord.

Comment: @ENORMOUZ give me a second to edit my answer.

Comment: @ENORMOUZ can you try this?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use print, print sends the message to the console, use `ctx.send` instead, for more information, check out the [discord.py documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html).

An example:

```py
ctx.send("Sending this to the designated channel on Discord")
```

Comment: Like I said, I already have it working as a bot command. However, I want it to prompt me when I start the program (So I do not have to open discord.